# White space bottom of website... can't find what causes it

Tags: magento-1.9, css

Our Magento Store is found [here](https://www.superstylishwebshop.com/en)

When scrolling to bottom there is white space below the footer maybe 20-30px

What could be causing this?

EDIT : I didn't do anything but for some reason it is not apparent anymore ???

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="_atssh" style="visibility: hidden;"><iframe id="_atssh606" title="AddThis utility frame" height="1px" width="1px" style="border: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></iframe></div>
```

Looks to be apart of AddThis script.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
<div id="_atssh" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

to

```
<div id="_atssh" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Font size is inherited, you just need to set the font-size to 0px for id #_atssh.
Worked with developer Tools in Browser for me.

See Screenshoot:
[image]